# Extract XML elements based on inner content

Tags: xml, parsing, sed, grep

I have a huge XML document (more than 12 GB) that I need to parse in the following way...

Given a structure like this:

```
<person name=Alice>
   <colour>blue</colour>
</person>

<person name=Bob>
   <colour>green</colour>
</person>

<person name=Charles>
   <colour>blue</colour>
</person>
```

I would like to extract in a separate file only those `person` elements that contains the subfield `<colour> blue </colour>`.

For example, given the previous XML code, the output of the program should be a separate file with the following content:

```
<person name=Alice>
   <colour>blue</colour>
</person>

<person name=Charles>
   <colour>blue</colour>
</person>
```

I have tried to use `grep` and `sed`, as they are very useful tools for this purpose and also can manage huge files like mine, but I'm not quite sure about the regex I should use.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: as I have noted, I need a stream-based tool, as otherwise the program simply crashes! I've tried `xmlstarlet` but the program is auto-killed (I suppose due to memory use).

**EDIT2**: I also tried to split the file using `xml_split`, but the amount of subfiles generated is simply untreatable. So, any suggestion?

Comment: Look into xidel.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @JackFleeting is stream-based? The problem is that, if not, the program is auto killed.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the XML aware tools you've tried so far work for you and if your input is as simple and regular as you posted then:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/<colour>blue</' file
<person name=Alice>
   <colour>blue</colour>
</person>

<person name=Charles>
   <colour>blue</colour>
</person>
```

If that's NOT all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.